# convergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x dx$ and exercise $10.24.15$ in Tom Apostol's calculus , vol. $1$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

In Tom Apostol's Calculus vol. $1$, section $10.23$ defines improper integrals, and it says that

> if $\int_{-\infty}^{c} f(x) dx$ and $\int_{c}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ are both convergent for some $c$, we say that the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ is convergent, and its value is defined to be the sum $\tag{10.62} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{c} f(x) dx + \int_{c}^{\infty} f(x) dx$. The integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ is said to diverge if at least one of the integrals on the right of $10.62$ is divergent.

From that definition, I would conclude that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x dx$ diverges, because both $\int_{-\infty}^{0} x dx$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty} x dx$ diverge.

However, when solving exercise $10.24.15$, which is to find constants $a, b$, for which:

$\lim_{p \to +\infty} \int_{-p}^{+p} \frac{x^3 + ax^2+bx}{x^2+x+1} dx = 1$

The solution of $a=1, b=1- \frac{\sqrt 3}{\pi}$ suggests that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x dx = 0$, which I could justify as:

$\lim_{b \to \infty} \int_{-b}^{0} x dx + \int_{0}^{b} x dx = \lim_{b \to \infty} -\int_{0}^{b} x dx + \int_{0}^{b} x dx = \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_{0}^{b} x - x dx = 0$

But how should I reconcile that with the definition given in the book? Is it because both positive and negative variables which tend to infinity are exactly the same in the exercise ($p$ and $-p$), unlike the ones in the definition (where they are $-\infty$ and $\infty$)?

Thanks!

Comment: The integral diverges, but can be regularized via Cauchy principal value (which is $0$).

Comment: The key thing here is that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x~\mathrm{d}x$ diverges, but $\lim_{p\to\infty}\int_{-p}^p x~\mathrm{d}x=0$. The first one is the usual improper integral, and the second one is the Cauchy principal value

Comment: The problem is asked you to calculate  Cauchy principal value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Remark** Why don't we always just use the principal value (PV) and dispense with this fussy "convergent" definition?    [Warning to physics students.]

Well, the PV fails to have many of the useful properties of the integral.  For example, if $f(x)$ is integrable on $(-\infty,+\infty)$ , then (with substitution $y=x-1, dy = dx$) we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\;dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y+1)\;dy .
$$
**Substitution** (even much more complicated substitution) is a basic tool for integration.  But it may fail for the PV.
Take $f(x) = x$, as in the OP question.  Then
$$
PV\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x\;dx = 
\lim_{p\to+\infty} \int_{-p}^p x\;dx =0
$$
But
$$
PV\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (y+1)\;dy = 
\lim_{p\to+\infty} \int_{-p}^p (y+1)\;dy = \lim_{p\to+\infty}(2p) = +\infty .
$$

---

**Exercise**
Find a substitution that similarly invalidates $$ \int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{x} = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you, professor! Tom Apostol hasn't introduced explicitly PV, and today is the first time I see it. To solve the $10.24.16.b$, I would say $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{dx}{x} = \int_{-1}^{0^-} \frac{dx}{x} + \int_{0^+}^{1} \frac{dx}{x} = \lim_{a \to 0^-} \int_{-1}^{a} \frac{dx}{x} + \lim_{b \to 0^+} \int_{b}^{1} \frac{dx}{x}$, and because $a$ and $b$ are different variables, we cannot cancel out the two diverging integrals, so the integral diverges, which agrees with the answer in the book. Your premise contradicts that [because it asserts that it converges to 0]. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I ued the word "invalidates" to say that $\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{x} = 0$ is false.